# How to pass url parameters to Vuejs

Tags: php, ajax, url, vue.js

I'm building an app with laravel and VueJs and I was wondering how to pass a url parameter like the user slug  or the user id to vuejs in a proper way to be able to use that parameter for making ajax requests?

For example when  someone clicks on a link leading to

```
domain.com/user/john-appleseed
```

I want to make an ajax request within my vuejs application with the slug 'john-appleseed' as a parameter.

What is the "right/proper" way to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you handle the routing? With vue.js or Laravel?

Comment: I use laravel for routing

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand, when the user click on the link, do you load the page and then make an ajax request or directly make the ajax request?

Comment: If a user visits a page then I want to make a ajax request to load the data instead of passing it to the view with laravel. This way I can use the data in vuejs to read/add/remove/update/show the data. But to make the ajax request (via vue-resource) I need to pass a parameter with an user identifier. Now the url has the parameter and I want to pass it in my vue instance to an ajax get request. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

[vue-router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router) would probably be of help here. It lets you define your routes like so:

```
router.map({
    '/user/:slug': {
        component: Profile,
        name: 'profile'
    },
})
```

Within your `Profile` component, the requested user's slug would then become available under `this.$route.params.slug`

Check the official documentation for details: http://router.vuejs.org/en/

Comment: Thanks @jsphpl. I found that the value was available under `this.$route.params.slug` instead of `$route.params.slug`. Not sure if it matters, but I'm using Vue 2.0.3.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you are building a component. Let's say, you have a button inside that component and when is clicked, you wanna perform an action (AJAX request, or just redirect).

In this case you pass the URL as parameter to the component and you can use it inside.

HTML:

```
<my-component login-url="get_url('url_token')">
```

Your component JS:

```
export default {
    props: {
        loginUrl: {required: true},
    },
    ...
}
```

Then you can access the param in the component as `this.loginUrl`.

Please notice that param name difference in HTML part as dash-notatinon and in JS as camelCase.

Comment: not sure what you meant to say with that get_url, it's kind of confusing, but the idea is valid

Answer (score 3):

If you are using vue-router and want to capture query parameters and pass them to props, you can do it this way.

Url being called : http://localhost:8080/#/?prop1=test1&prop2=test2

MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{prop1}} {{prop2}}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    props: {
      prop1: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      prop2: {
        type: String,
        default:'prop2'
      }
    }
</script>
<style></style>
```

router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'

Vue.use (Router) 
Vue.component ('my-component', MyComponent)

export default new Router ({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'MyComponent',
      component: MyComponent,
      props: (route) => ({
        prop1: route.query.prop1,
        prop2: route.query.prop2
      })
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the url of the link you click and then use this url to do your ajax request.

```
methods: {
    load: function(elem, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = e.target.href;
        this.$http.get(url, function (data, status, request) {
            // update your vue 
        });
    },
},
```

And in your template call this method when the user click on a link:

```
<a href="domain.com/user/john-appleseed" v-on="click: load">link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

either using the $route of the vue:

```js
const User = {
  template: '<div>User {{ $route.params.id }}</div>'
}
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{ path: '/user/:id', component: User }]
})
```

or you can decouple it by using ***props***

```js
const User = {
  props: ['id'],
  template: '<div>User {{ id }}</div>'
}
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: true },

    // for routes with named views, you have to define the `props` option for each named view:
    {
      path: '/user/:id',
      components: {
        default: User,
        sidebar: Sidebar
      },
      props: {
        default: true,
        // function mode, more about it below
        sidebar: route => ({ search: route.query.q })
      }
    }
  ]
})
```