# Link to a route with a parameter of Vue.js

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js and Laravel to render a simple table listing products. From there I want to link to a product detail page like this:

`<a href="{{ route("product::details", ['product' => '???']) }}">@{{ product.id }}</a>`

Since the table is generated on client side base on a data object, I'm looking for the most elegant way to implement that while not bypassing any laravel methods like `route()` that allows me to link to a named route.

Do I really have to manually merge the result of the route-method with the Vue variable in Javascript?

In my mind is something like:

`<a href="{{ route("product::details", ['product' => ':product.id']) }}">@{{ product.id }}</a>`

which I could probably parse/inject by Vue via data binding?

Comment: Similar to the following question, but I need to merge "backend parameters" into the link target: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560184/how-to-pass-url-parameters-to-vuejs

Comment: Are you using laravel or vue-router for your routing?  I can't think of a way this would work off the top of my head, as both of them either require a path, or a named route + parameters

Comment: I'm using laravel for routing.

Comment: hmm, have you tried `<a href="{{ route("product::details", ['product' => '@{{ product.id }}']) }}">@{{ product.id }}</a>` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Vue it's client side and laravel it's server side you can't accomplish that in that way.

But you can do something like this over the rendered route:

Create a vue method

```
goto_route: function (param1) {
     route = '{{ route("yournamedroute", ["yourparameter" => "?anytagtoreplace?"]) }}'
     location.href = route.replace('?anytagtoreplace?', param1)
}
```

Now in your action element

```
<div v-for="o in object">
     <a v-on:click="goto_route(o.id_key)">press</a>
</div>
```

Basically you're replacing the... uhmm... let's name it "placehoder" in the rendered route with the required value.

hope it helps.