# Pass vue.js parameters using route name to laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, vue.js

I fetch data using vue.js into my view, so I want to pass parameters via vue.js to this route name. Like this:

```
<img :src="{{ route('getImage', image.path) }}" />
```

I've tried various approaches but without success:

```
<img src="{{ route('getImage', :image.path) }}" />
<img src="{{ route('getImage', @{{ image.path }} ) }}" />
<img src="{{ route('getImage', '@{{ image.path }}' ) }}" />
```

The basic method that works

```
<img :src="'/img/'+image.path" />
```

The controller:

```
public function getImage($filename, $params){ }
```

I want to pass more than one parameter to this route. Please any ideas.

**Update:** The question is already posted here but without solutions: [Link to a route with a parameter of Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200017/link-to-a-route-with-a-parameter-of-vue-js?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to combine javascript and php, why not create the full path in image.path?

Comment: My images are stored locally and use this controller to have access, `$file = Storage::diks('xxxx')->get($filename);` So I prefer to don't have duplicate paths in my db.

Comment: Both paths might not need to be stored though. It could be a derived attribute depending on your naming conventions. Sorry if this doesn't help, I don't know enough about your project.